# Web Config | 302 redirect doubled the url

Tags: redirect, iis, web-config, http-status-code-302

I'm using 302 redirect from external domain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://www.example.com" httpResponseStatus="Found">
            <clear />
        </httpRedirect>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

After the redirect the new domain look like this: `https://www.example.com/,http://www.example.com`

This the web.config of the target domain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="index.html" />
                <add value="default.asp" />
                <add value="default.aspx" />
                <add value="index.php" />
                <add value="index.asp" />
                <add value="home.aspx" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^system.*" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^application.*" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I've tried many versions of 302 redirect, but it seems that the url doubled in the target domain.. what would make it happen?

Comment: Try to add `exactDestination="true"` to the `<httpRedirect>` element: `<httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://www.example.com" httpResponseStatus="Found" exactDestination="true">`. Otherwise, IIS considers the redirection to be *relative* to the attempted path.

Comment: It returns `https://www.example.com%2Chttp//www.example.com`